# Why does my docker container exit after run command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My docker image was created from below Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
CMD ping 8.8.8.8
```

when I run below command, the container existed immediately.

```
docker run -d d1 bash
```

but if I run below command, I am able to attach on the shell in the container:

```
docker run -it d1 bash
```

I don't know why the first command doesn't create a shell in the container.

**EDIT1**

I want my container running at the background so I can attach to it at a later time. But after running the first command, the container got stopped and I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command does create a shell, but it's run disconnected without any input attached. So just as if you ran `bash </dev/null` the shell immediately exits after reaching the end of stdin. If you run `docker run -itd d1 bash` you will have a tty and stdin attached to the shell so it doesn't exit, but disconnected. You can also pick other commands to run, e.g. `docker -d d1 tail -f /dev/null`.